# How to use inheritance, what am i missing?

Tags: python, inheritance, pygame, overriding

I'm new to python and i'm trying to practice some basic concepts.
I'm trying to build a basic model of the sun and the earth spinning around it.
I've got 2 classes, 1 class inherits from the other, but it seems that the "Father" class is using a function from the "son" class...
And what happens that instead the sun being stationary it spins with the earth ><
What am i doing wrong?

```
from math import cos, sin
pygame.init()

win_size = width, height = 800, 800
center_screen = [center_x, center_y] = [int(width/2), int(height/2)]

window = pygame.display.set_mode(win_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Testing")


class Star(object):
    def __init__(self, location, size, color):
        self.location = location
        self.size = size
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, self.location, self.size, 0)


class Planet(Star):
    def __init__(self, location, size, color, speed, r):
        Star.__init__(self, location, size, color)
        self.alpha = 0
        self.r = r
        self.speed = speed

    def draw(self, win):
        self.set_pos()
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, self.location, self.size, 0)

    def set_pos(self):
        self.location[0] = int(self.r*cos(self.alpha)) + center_x
        self.location[1] = int(self.r*sin(self.alpha)) + center_y
        self.alpha += 1


sun = Star(center_screen, 20, (255, 255, 0))
earth = Planet(center_screen, 10, (0, 0, 255), 2, 100)


def redraw_game_window():
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    sun.draw(window)
    earth.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(200)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False

    redraw_game_window()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I don't understand the first question: the only function the parent class calls is `pygame.draw.circle`; I don't see where it uses anything from `Planet`.  The position problem is because  you've given a single, master `position` to serve for all objects.  To be sure of this, print out that variable as you change and use it.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

> ```py
> self.location = location
> ```

then the instance variable `self.location` stores a reference to the list `location`, but it doesn't create a copy of the list. So at the end  alt the objects refer to the same list  of data.
Note, in python a variable name is a reference to an object. The data is contained in the object. When you do an assignment, then the reference is assigned and both variables refer to the same object.

Copy the list to solve the issue:

```py
self.location = location[:]
```

`[:]` crates a shallow  copy of a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).